# Prove that if a $f '$is always rational, $f$ is a straight line

Tags: real-analysis

$f$ is a function from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that $f'\left( x \right)$, the derivative of $f$, is always a rational number. Prove that the graph of $f$ is a straight line.

Comment: Do you know [Darboux’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $f'(x)$ is continuous, and that the domain of $f(x)$ is some (possibly infinite) open interval $I$, pick $x_1 \in I$.  Then $f'(x_1)$ is rational.  Pick $x_2 \in I$, with $x_2 > x_1$.  If $f'(x_2) \ne f'(x_1)$, the continuity of $f'(x)$ coupled with the intermediate value theorem forces $f'(x)$ to take on every value 'twixt $f'(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$.  But there exists an irrational number $s$ between these two values of $f'(x)$.  Thus there exists $x_3 \in [x_1, x_2]$ with $f'(x_3) = s$, contradicting the assumption that $f'(x)$ is always rational.  So $f'(x)$ can only take on the constant rational value $f'(x_1)$.  Since $f'(x)$ is constant, the graph of $f(x)$ is a straight line.  ***QED***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: You don't need $f'$ to be continuous, you just need Darboux's theorem.

Comment: @ nik:  As I just learned by reading the wiki page to which Brian M. Scott linked in his comment.  I was unsure of this when I typed my answer, which is why I explicitly restricted my answer to the case $f'(x)$ continuous.  Why don't you write something up and post an answer?  I think a cogent explanation might garner some upvotes, if this question stays open long enough! :-(!!!  But thanks for the input!